# ObjC animation won't run

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to change my view background color with this animation, it should change from blue to red to green but it won't run, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation * anim = [ CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor" ] ;
anim.values = @[ [UIColor blueColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor] ] ;
anim.autoreverses = NO;
anim.repeatCount = 7.20f ;     
anim.duration = 0.1f ;

UIWindow *win = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];
[win.rootViewController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add animation to CALayer. CALayer's backgroundColor property have type CGColorRef, not UIColor. I've modified your code in the following way to make it work:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
anim.values = @[(__bridge id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
                (__bridge id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor],
                (__bridge id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
anim.repeatCount = 7.20f ;
anim.duration = 10.0f ;
[self.window.rootViewController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```